# Pandas string with none to int conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a column with datatype string. I want to convert it to int using pandas.

The dataframe column has values such as:

```
1
2
None
```

I am using pandas to convert it to int.

```
df['column'] = pd.to_numeric(df[column],errors='coerce').fillna(0)
print(df.dtypes)
print(df)
```

It prints:

object and values such as:

```
"1"
"2"
"None"
```

Comment: Did you intend `df['column']` where you have `df[column]`?

Comment: So what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: You might have to use a numpy array pandas does not allow nan in integer columns have a look  at this http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the `pd.to_numeric()` function is not successfully converting the string values to integers. This could be because the string values contain non-numeric characters, such as whitespace or non-numeric symbols.

To convert a column of strings to integers using Pandas, you can use the `astype()` method. If you need to handle missing or invalid values, you can use the `fillna()` method to replace them with a default value:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

This will replace any missing or invalid values with 0, then attempt to convert the strings to integers.

If you want to preserve the missing values in the column, you can use `pd.to_numeric()` with the `errors='coerce'` argument to convert non-numeric values to NaN, then use `fillna()` to replace the NaN values with a default value:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column': ['1', '2', 'None', '3', '4', '5']
})

# Convert the string column to integers
df['column'] = pd.to_numeric(df['column'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

does this work for you ?

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'column':['1','2','3',None]})
data["new_column"]=data["column"].map(lambda x : int(x) if x!= None else np.nan) #np.nan or None or 0 or whatever you want.
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
df['column'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```